# Is Occam's razor a philosophical application of Occam's razor itself in epistemology? Is it a meta for itself?

Tags: occams-razor, self-reference, recursion, circular-reasoning

I have to apologize for my title but this seems to me the only way I could have articulated this weird intuitive idea I had for the Occam's razor meta-analysis. Usually I tend to analyze things on the basis of themselves (recursively) partially due to my background in programming and so the title is not as appealing or clear, but bear with me.

In my understanding, I see that Occam's razor is the principle, most often used in the scientific setting to choose the least complex/simplest and most reasonable explanation that fits well within the realms of what is being observed, so my question goes along the lines of: Did William Occam in a way develop his reasoning for the principle of Occam's razor through a method or an intuition that made use of Occam's razor principle, I say this because to pick the simplest and most reasonable method is the simplest and reasonable method in and of itself, or am I wrong?

I am not entirely sure where I am going with this and I understand that my question might not result in an ulterior or significant implication, but are there any implications to my understanding of the formulation and development of Occam's razor.

In a different way, my question begs if the application of Occam's razor was inherent to the formulation of Occam's razor? Or was it not? Does applying the principle of the 'already existing' Occam's razor might not actually be the simplest yet most reasonable thing to do? Could using the principle Occam's razor in the realm of epistemology yield something even simpler and more reasonable i.e., "a razor sharper than Occam's razor (metaphorically speaking)" or does applying it result in Occam's razor exactly holding that Occam's razor is indeed the simplest and most reasonable principle that could be formulated or possibly conceived.

I guess in the simplest of terms, I am asking if the idea of Occam's razor supposes Kant's claim of transcendental deduction i.e., from my understanding of Kant's claim that intuition presupposes any logical thought, thus supposing it was an innate intuition of Occam's razor that led to the principle of Occam's razor?

If there is anything wrong you think I have said in previous lines, please correct me and give an explanation.

Comment: I think this is an interesting idea. I don't have any other thoughts about it yet.

Comment: Occam's razor is only a rule of thumb... simple ideas and hypotheses are easy to manage compared to complex ones. There is no way to "prove" it.

Comment: Self-supporting systems or ideas have an inherent beauty, and in hindsight Occam's razor is kind of self-supporting. But I doubt that he thought about this reflectivity when he wrote his formulation of the principle. In computer science, creating self-supporting systems (such as compilers which can compile themselves) always requires some sort of "bootstrap" from some simpler system.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I agree, but what does this say about ideas or even the formulation of ideas and determinism. To think about such principles, was it purely conscious and deliberate or more of intuitive and subconscious, just like Mauro above mentions that it is just a rule of thumb or is it pointing to something beyond the conscious thinking.

Comment: This actually resonates quite deeply with some things I've been thinking about recently. For example in the philosophy of language, aren't we using language to talk about language? Isn't there something circular about the logic there? Is that a bad thing? And I find similar dilemmas in modern logic and mathematics. How can we apply set theory to first order logic when set theory is axiomatized by first order logic? I'm beginning to believe there's something more meta at hand that we aren't recognizing when we talk about theories and their models, although I haven't thought about it enough yet.

Comment: @how-why-e it's likely impossible what happened in the mind of someone who lived 700 years ago if they didn't write about their reasoning themselves. I'm not familiar with his writings so I don't know whether there is something to that effect.

Comment: @Joseph_Kopp It is truly impressive how in a lot of abstract settings even in maths thinking about the Mandelbrot's set how there are exact replicas of the system/figure we began with embedded within itself. This might sound crazy but I feel it is just an evidence of how we as subjective beings are stuck within this realm of shared/collective subjective reality (the reality we assume or perceive and its outcomes like logic and reason) and that we can never truly grasp the world as it truly 'objectively' is.

Comment: @Howwhye I completely agree. In physics for example, I think the most beautiful and intuitive theory would be one which justifies itself, circularly. There's always Hume's problem of infinite recursion with any question about the "origin" of things. I think the only reasonable solution is that at some point the answer to "why?" begins repeating itself in a pattern, like a repeating decimal, as opposed to this dream people have of discovering some kind of "objective truth" from which all is derived. I don't think it's possible and it feels idealistic. I'm happy that you think similarly.

Comment: I read this post as a historical question as to whether William of Ockham used the principle he developed as part of the process of developing it.  As such whether there is an answer would depend on what he wrote about his intellectual process in generating the idea.  If you are instead asking the distinct question about whether Occam's Razor is motivated by or consistent with self appication, I'd suggest rewriting the questions in the final paragraph.

Comment: @Dave When originally asked I did not intend it on being a historical question but the question inherently has historical facets to it. For instance if history was fully complete and objective or say that I was asking this question to William himself, he would have revealed his thought process giving me insight to the development of the principle, but I see what you mean and I have edited it, thank you. I hope that captures a different intent different to a historical inquiry.

Comment: The concept of a 'metaphor' is itself a meta metaphor.

Comment: The second to last paragraph reads to me that you are falling into the trap of thinking that simplicity, by itself, should be considered a factor in model selection (in this case a model about how to select models).  The "prefer simpler" is only in play when you have more than one competing model that are all equally descriptive of the evidence available.  It's possible that, in fact, one could demonstrate that applying this principle /tends to work/ when it is applicable; thus providing an emprical proof.  I don't know that anyone has.

Comment: @Dave True, I see what you are saying, I am indeed trapped by the idea that simplicity is a factor to be considered, but I would like to make the suggestion: shouldn't it be inherently so. You are right I will agree that there seems to be no demonstration or adaptation that is competing with Occam's razor and therefore applying it to itself just stems from the inherent requirement of simplicity, but hypothetically speaking I have suggested hypothetical competing models in my question.

Comment: "Did O develop his reasoning for the principle of O's razor through a method or an intuition that made use of O's razor principle?" There are [Okham's texts](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ockham/#OckhRazo): "the slogan known as “O’s Razor,” often expressed as “Don’t multiply entities beyond necessity.” *Although the sentiment is certainly O’s, that particular formulation is nowhere to be found in his texts*. [...] As he says in *Sent*.I:“For nothing ought to be posited without a reason given, unless it is self-evident or known by experience or proved by the authority of Sacred Scripture.”

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So it is indeed suggesting it is self-evident and that Occam's Razor is based on Occam's razor?

Comment: In what sense? The principle is formulated by O in the context of the "realism-nominalism" debate: an entity (e.g. using a more modern example: gravity or magnetic field) must not be assumed as existent unless: its existence is evident (e.g. my personal existence?), or known by experience (e.g. the existence of the sun?), or "proved" by authority of the Sacred Scripture (e.g. Jesus Christ).

Comment: See Armand Maurer, [Ockham's Razor (1984)](https://philpapers.org/rec/MAUORA-2)  for context: "the oldest version of the axiom dates from the middle of the 13th Century and is due to [Odo Rigaldus](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudes_Rigaud): "Frsutra fit per plura quod potest fieri per unum." "

Comment: Okay, thank you very much!

Comment: But the "rule" is already in Aristotle; see *An.Post*, 86a34-86a36: "Let that demonstration be better which, other things being equal, depends on fewer postulates or suppositions or propositions. For if they are equally familiar,
knowing will come about more quickly in this way; and that is preferable."